# Fail to patch rc by api?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes verison: 1.02

PATCH /api/v1/namespaces/default/replicationcontrollers/test

```
body  
{"spec":  
{"replicas": 3}  
}  

response  
'{  
"kind": "Status",  
"apiVersion": "v1",  
"metadata": {},  
"status": "Failure",  
"message": "the server responded with the status code 415 but did not return more information",  
"details": {},  
"code": 415  
}'
```

Is this a bug for API?

Answer (score 6):

For PATCH to work you need to send one of the [accepted content-type header values](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/devel/api-conventions.html#patch-operations).

Your example uses a [merge patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386), so you should send:

```
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json
```

Comment: Thanks, missed the CONSUMES part in docs - https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/rest_api/openshift_v1.html#consumes-128