# Fail to delete rc by api?

Tags: kubernetes

kubernetes version:1.02
REST api
DELETE /api/v1/namespaces/default/replicationcontrollers/test
body

```
{
"apiVersion": "v1",
"kind": "ReplicationController",
"gracePeriodSeconds": 0}
}
```

Fail

```
{
"kind": "Status",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {},
"status": "Failure",
"message": "converting to : type names don't match (ReplicationController, DeleteOptions), and no conversion 'func (v1.ReplicationController, api.DeleteOptions) error' registered.",
"code": 500
}
```

if setting body is empty, delete success, but pod is exist.
kubectl get rc, rc is deleted
kubectl get pod, pod is existting

why?
How can I delete rc with all pods by api delete method?

Answer (score 0):

API requests are designed to be able to be fulfilled immediately. Tasks like reaping/recursively deleting are typically handled by a client by combining multiple API requests. In this case, you can do what `kubectl` does when running `kubectl delete rc/test` (which you can see by adding `--v=8`):

1. Set the spec.replicas of rc/test to 0
2. Watch until status.replicas of rc/test is also 0
3. Delete rc/test

Comment: Don't set replicas by api.   Fail to patch rc by api.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205116/fail-to-patch-rc-by-api